# accounts-js GraphQL client side authenticate mutation not working

Tags: javascript, apollo-client, apollo-server, graphql-js

In the Apollo GraphQL playground I have the following mutation:

```
mutation {
  authenticate(
    serviceName: "password"
    params: {
      user: { email: "john.doe@john.com" }
      password: "superSecurePassword"
    }
  ) {
    sessionId
    tokens {
      accessToken
      refreshToken
    }
    user {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Client side I try the following:

```
export const LOGIN_USER = gql`
  mutation Authenticate($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    authenticate(email: $email, password: $password) {
      id
      token
    }
  }
`;
```

An exception is thrown:

```
 46 | // Constructs an instance of ApolloError given a GraphQLError
 47 | // or a network error. Note that one of these has to be a valid
 48 | // value or the constructed error will be meaningless.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

export const LOGIN_USER = gql`mutation Authenticate($email: String!, $password: String!) { authenticate(email: $email, password: $password)  { sessionId tokens { accessToken refreshToken } user { id } } }`;

Comment: Hey, thank you Ibrahim but it doesn't work. What particulary confuses me is the  serviceName: "password" and that the email attribute that is passed in as an argument is nested in a user object. How to translate that into a client side code?